# How to set User property to "Purchasers" in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-notifications, firebase-console

Unfortunately, Firebase documentation is incomplete.

There is a filter inside Firebase *Analytics* panel:

[image: Firebase Analytics Screenshot]

And Firebase *Notifications* panel:

[image: Firebase Notifications Screenshot]

Which allows to filter users, but there is no instructions on how to set a user property as a **Purchasers** in the documentation.

The only description about **Purchasers** in the documents is this [link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en#management-table).

I think there must be a command like this:

```
firebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("USER_TYPE", "PURCHASERS"/"NONPURCHASERS");
```

But I have no clue about the Property name or the Value. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The **Purchasers** Audience is one of the two predefined Audience available (the other one being **All Users**), wherein a *Purchaser* is defined as:

> Users who have **completed an in-app purchase or ecommerce purchase**.

-- [**source**](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en#management-table)

I think that pretty much explains it on how a user is labeled as a *Purchaser*.

You can however, create your own Audience if you prefer (from the same source above):

> **Create an audience**
>
> You create an audience by defining criteria that reference any of the user properties and events (along with any of their parameters) logged by the app. Once created, an audience accumulates users who meet the specified criteria from that point onward. You can create up to 50 audiences.
>
> To create a new audience:
>
> 1. In Firebase Analytics, click the **Audiences** tab.
> 2. Click **NEW AUDIENCE**.
> 3. Enter a name and description for the audience. This name and description will allow you to identify the audience in the management table.
> 4. Click **Select Event or User Property**.
> 5. Create one or more conditions that define who should be included in this audience. You can create conditions that include the users who have taken specific actions (**Event**) or who share a property (**User Property**). Combine multiple conditions with **OR** or **AND**.
> 6. Click **Create** to save your conditions and create the audience.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can create your Purchasers audience:

1. Click audience on the left-side menu
2. Click new audience on the top right
3. Select a filter > choose event > choose in_app_purchase
4. Click add a parameter
5. count > greater than 0